# What's wrong with my PDO/MySQL syntax?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using the following code:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT into crm_order_errors "
                      ."SET (order_id, number_of_attempts, last_attempt) "
                      ."VALUES (:order_id, 0, :last_attempt) "
                      ."ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE number_of_attempts = number_of_attempts + 1, last_attempt = :last_attempt"
         );

$query->execute(array(':order_id'=>$orderId, ':last_attempt'=>1332849904);
```

This produces the following error:

> PHP Warning:  PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error
>   or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check
>   the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '(order_id, number_of_attempts, last_attempt)
>   VALUES ('10297', 0, '' at line 1 in
>   /_myClasses/MYSQL_Logger.php
>   on line 57

It simply isn't clear to me where the error is. It appears that the value for `:last_attempt` is not getting found, since the warning puts its value at `''`: `Values ('10297', 0, ''`. Why is that happening, and is that the source of the problem?

Also, am I allowed to use the same placeholder twice in a prepared statement (in this case, `:last_attempt`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an end parenthesis on your `execute` function.

Should be:

```
$query->execute(array(':order_id'=>$orderId, ':last_attempt'=>1332849904));
```

And you need to remove the `SET` keyword. It's for `UPDATE` statements, not `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Thanks, it was the SET keyword. The missing parenthesis was just a copy & paste error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `SET` in the SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a parenthesis:

```
$query->execute(array('order_id' => $orderId, 'last_attempt' => 1332849904));
```

Also remove `SET` from your `INSERT INTO` statement.